# Adobe Photoshop

Tags: 14.04, adobe

Recently I have switched my OS from Windows to Ubuntu 14.04, but I need **Adobe Photoshop** to run for my project.  So how can I run Adobe Photoshop on Ubuntu, or are there any Ubuntu plugin like photo editor software?

Answer (score 1):

I'm an Ubuntu user caught in a similar situation with Adobe Creative Cloud [at school]. So if you must use Photoshop in Ubuntu ... then there's 2 options:

a.) Run Photoshop under Wine-HQ;

- Only certain versions of Photoshop and Wine-HQ work.

b.) Use virtualization to run Photoshop in a Windows guest operating system.

I chose virtualization. But found that there's drawbacks if you don't have the right hardware, or pick the right virtualization program to run a guest OS.

This is because Photoshop needs 3D acceleration and plenty of VRAM to work *like it's suppose to, and not complain via pop-up warning* .... So if you're on a production system, mapping out a game plan is a priority, to avoid tears later.

From what I've come to understand, the best results for Photoshop with virtualization needs:

- It's standard system requirements.
- CPU with Vt-d or AMD-virtualization(TM); and IOMMU
- Enable Virtualization and IOMMU in Bios/UEFI
- 2 Graphics cards (1 is dedicated to the Guest OS. For instance, use onboard or integrated graphics for host, and GPU for virtualization).
- And of course ... you gotta have power to run both the host (Ubuntu), and Windows guest (Win can be CPU hog when the guest is first turned on).

---

NOTE: I can use Photoshop CC 2014 with only 1 Graphics card, and 256MB of VRAM in Virtualbox. But it prevents me from using 3D effects, etc.

PS: I just read a post about Pixeluvo being a strong competitor to Photoshop (by an alleged "pro"). It's an inexpensive commercial app, with a native program for Ubuntu (see: http://www.pixeluvo.com).

Answer (score 0):

There is a vector image draw tool in Ubuntu called **inkscape**. Follow these steps to install **inkscape**.

**Open terminal(Crtl+Alt+T) and execute following commands one by one**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable

sudo apt-get update 

sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

There is another photo editor software (easier to use than inkscape) called **gimp**. Follow these steps to install **gimp**

**Open terminal(Crtl+Alt+T) and execute following commands one by one**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

[Check these tutorials for using inkscape (Click here)](http://speckyboy.com/2009/04/28/35-tutorials-to-create-amazing-vector-graphics-using-inkscape/)

Comment: As mentioned, Inkscape is a vector drawing program. This is nothing like Photoshop. Gimp is much more similar, although it suffers from a missing features compared to Photoshop.

Comment: If it answers your question, accept the answer by clicking the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "the answer is valid"

Comment: The tick doesn't exactly mean "the answer is valid"; it means it's the *best* answer. There can be more than one valid answer, but only once accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to work on WINE but I tried installing it on CS6 and failed miserably on every try. However there is a much easier way:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

It's got an installation script for Photoshop CS6 (works like a charm!), here it is:
https://www.playonlinux.com/pl/app-2316-Adobe_Photoshop_CS6.html

There's also a script for [Illustrator CS6](https://www.playonlinux.com/pl/app-2731.html).
Supposedly those scripts might work with CC versions, but I haven't tested that. If you need the latest CC you can always use VirtualBox.